# Cohort study modeling with lmer multilevel correlations

Tags: mixed-model

I am studying the correlation between 20 different metrics in a dataset collected from 8 different cohorts (groups of people). My main objective is to create clusters of highly correlated metrics, so I can select a representative one for each cluster.

So, the structure of the data is something like this:

[image: Each of the metric is computed for each sample. The cohort group the samples. No sample is present in more than one Cohort.]

- Each metric is computed for every sample.
- The cohort groups the samples.
- No sample is present in more than one cohort.

The regression line could be very different for each cohort depending on the metrics that are being compared...

[image]

I tried a model with uncorrelated random intercept and slope to obtain the R2 for each pariwise metric correlation, but I am not sure if this is the correct/best option.

```
model <- lme4::lmer(Metric1 ~ Metric2 + (1|Cohort) + (0 + Metric2|Cohort), data = data)
performance::r2(model)
```